# What's the significant improve from UML 2.0 to UML 1.4?

Tags: uml, standards

BTW,what's the latest version of UML,and how often does it release a new version?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware there's no regular release schedule. As for the differences between versions, you can find a summary for example [here](http://woshiadai.blogsome.com/2005/09/07/a-quick-comparison-of-uml-14-and-20/), probably a bit more readable [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language).

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of UML is UML 2.2 which is built on the top of xmi 2.1.
See more at: http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=uml2

Answer (score 0):

> What's the significant improve from UML 2.0 to UML 1.4?

The site [**uml-diagrams.org**](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/index.html) present a comprehensive summary of changes from version to version. As it's a bit long for a quote, I won't quote the answer, and let people read it on the above link.

> BTW,what's the latest version of UML

Depens on the point of view. At the time of writing, the latest ISO approved is UML 1.4.2 (2005), the latest OMG final is UML 2.4.1 (2011) and the latest OMG published is UML 2.5 (2012 - 2013).

> and how often does it release a new version?

I know ISO as some timing requirement, but I don't know any for the OMG. UML is continuously evolving with so called “minor updates”.